# Is economics a science according to Popperian and Lakatosian standards?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-economics, demarcation

According to Karl Popper's falsification criterion only a falsifiable theory is said to be a scientific theory. If this is true, is Economics falsifiable and hence considered scientific?

Comment: Is this for a class? What of Popper and Lakatos was assigned to read? Is this based on what *they* said about economics? Or was "economics" defined more specifically and *you* are supposed to apply their criteria to that? We do not answer one-liners without more context, and some indication of personal effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to falsify economics or science. **You are conflating theories, methods, and disciplines.** Good theories are falsifiable, disciplines are not. Like most disciplines, some aspects are falsifiable and others are not, and that a discipline has some aspects that are not falsifiable doesn't eliminate it as a science. A perfect example is astronomy which studies many phenomena that cannot be falsified directly. Karl Popper and his [critical rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_rationalism) was a great counterweight to the [logical positivists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism) he criticized, but falsification is only one aspect of what generally constitutes scientific methods. To boot, economics does have theories that can be tested such as those of [behavioral economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_economics), among others. [What constitutes a science is subject to controversy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem) and interpretation, such as the dispute between [realists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_realism) and [intstrumentalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentalism).

Besides, [falsification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability#Falsificationism) can be practiced in economics through trial and error in fiscal policy. A classic example of an often touted, but thoroughly discredited economic theory is that of [trickle-down economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trickle-down_economics). [Supply-side economic theory has been tested as fiscal policy repeatedly over the last hundred years, and the effects consistently fail to create economic growth](https://www.newsweek.com/brownbacks-failure-kansas-dooms-gop-economics-628705). Money simply doesn't trickle down, the most recent evidence is [recent Kansas fiscal policy](https://www.newsweek.com/brownbacks-failure-kansas-dooms-gop-economics-628705).

By most reasonable definitions of a science, economics passes muster.